# How run django with pm2?

Tags: python, django, pm2

I have a django project on ubuntu 18.04 
I wanna `start` and `stop` it with `pm2`. 
I've created a `django_project.yml` file with the following contents:

```
apps:
  - cwd: 'directory_that_manage.py_exists_in_it'
    script: './manage.py runserver'
    args: 'server --binding 0.0.0.0'
    interpreter: 'python3'
    name     : 'django_project'
    instances: 1
    watch  : false
    exec_mode: fork_mode
```

then, I run it with the following command:

```
pm2 start django_project.yml --interpreter ../.env/bin/python3
```

it starts, but after `stop` it and `start` it again, it gets the following errors.
[image: pm2 errors in my system]

what is the problem?
please help me. thanks

Comment: You see similar problem if you run `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: no, at all. my app is run on the server without any problem.

Comment: I think you write something in line 2 using other languages (maybe chines or others) which is not correctly or fully defined , so it gives you a UTF-8 Error

Comment: where is exactly?

Comment: as it shows it's in line 2 but it seems to be a long sentence in that line and because it shows you "\x82" which its a byte , so I suggest you to copy and paste that line in a new python file and put it in a simple print() and try using enters to break that line to several part then you can understand where the problem is (after each enter run the file to see if it gives you error or not)

Comment: I had same problem with chines long sentences while web scrapping so I did that and made a line to 7 parts and it worked OK

Comment: Sorry I think your problem is in line 1